# Use google maps javascript api on my cordova project

Tags: google-maps, cordova, whitelist

I want to use google maps javascript api on my cordova project. I noticed by a lot of search to need to implement white list policy in config.xml. But I can't understand what to implement in config.xml. Please help. Followings are my codes and trial result.

---config.xml---

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="net.thinctank.onmap" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Map</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

---

---index.html---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

---index.js---

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

---

I tried to execute by "cordova serve android" command but i got the error↓
"Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."